# Backbone collection.get() not working

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm trying to filter through a collection of lists in my router to show a particular list in a new view.

My collection of lists has already been fetched and is saved at MyApp.collections.lists, but when I try to do the following, it returns undefined. (id is a variable that I'm passing in from the router)

```
var list = MyApp.collections.lists.get(id)
```

What I don't get is that when I try the exact same code in the browser console, it returns the correct model no problem. I know it's not an issue with .fetch() timing because I log the collection object before and after I try to get the model and it shows up fine. I also know I also tried .getByCid() just to make sure that it wasn't a problem with the id itself and got the same results.

Any ideas what might be causing this?

Comment: So after some more testing, I discovered that even though the collection was showing up in the log with all of the data before the .get() call, .fetch() was not yet actually finished. So it was a .fetch() timing issue after all. I thought that the fact that the object was being logged proved that the fetch was done, but the "success" callback on fetch proved otherwise.

Comment: "the collection was showing up in the log with all of the data": some `console.log`s are async so you can't always trust them, if you clone the data that you're logging (`console.log(collection.toJSON())` or similar) then you should get more reliable results.

Comment: Hi Will, is the lists an instance on Backbone.Collection?